# How do you include debug info for assembly files in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, debug-information

For debug info, I have these config options enabled:

```
/Volumes/git/linux (master)*$ grep CONFIG_DEBUG build/.config | grep -v ^#
CONFIG_DEBUG_ALIGN_RODATA=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_DWARF_TOOLCHAIN_DEFAULT=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_LL_INCLUDE="mach/debug-macro.S"
```

However the vmlinux file only includes debug info for .c and .h files and not .S files.

Is there a standard way to get debug info for the assembly files included in vmlinux?

update 8/2/2022:

I found that in scripts/Makefile.debug if you use LLVM/clang then debug info is excluded from assembly files for some reason.

```
ifndef CONFIG_AS_IS_LLVM
KBUILD_AFLAGS   += -Wa,-gdwarf-2
endif
```

and removing the ifndef line fixed the missing debug info for me.

Why is `ifndef CONFIG_AS_IS_LLVM` there?

Comment: What specifically is the issue?  Debug messages are sent to the console.  Code can simply call a routine to send such debug messages, either from C or assembly language.  Review **arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S** for an example.

Comment: @sawdust The specific issue is described above.

Comment: You have three concepts of debug.  'debug-macro.S' is a way to print information in early boot.  Then there is debug like `gdb` or symbolic information that an external program will use.  For assembler, you have to use pseudo ops to add the information.  Generally assembler is a direct 1-1 mapping.  Only routine entry/exit points normally have debug information.  3rd could be some sort of linux debug mechanics. You did not describe the 'debug' you want; it is a generic term which grep does not distinguish.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if building with llvm clang, remove `ifndef CONFIG_AS_IS_LLVM` and `endif` from around the `KBUILD_AFLAGS`

```
diff --git a/scripts/Makefile.debug b/scripts/Makefile.debug
index 9f39b0130551f..1a26df0538b5b 100644
--- a/scripts/Makefile.debug
+++ b/scripts/Makefile.debug
@@ -6,9 +6,7 @@ else
 DEBUG_CFLAGS   += -g
 endif
 
-ifndef CONFIG_AS_IS_LLVM
 KBUILD_AFLAGS  += -Wa,-gdwarf-2
-endif
 
 ifndef CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_DWARF_TOOLCHAIN_DEFAULT
 dwarf-version-$(CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_DWARF4) := 4
```